# DataGridView to Update database

Tags: c#, datagrid, oledb

I have a `datagridview` that I programmatically filled with data using database connection.

Like this:

```
myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataTable)
myDataGridView.DataSource = myDataAdapter
```

I have set a column that can be edited. It was a inventory `datagridview` where I can restock by just clicking on a column and type. My question is:

How can I programmatically update each row of the edited column in my database based on my datagrid?

Comment: This is too broad. There are too many ways to answer this question. you need to be more specific. try something and if you still had a problem, get beck here and ask

Comment: I tried sql using oledbcommand which I used to get the dataset. I tried to use update table set database_column = datagridview_column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the cell edit event of datagridview like below

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //
   Need to add your code here.
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah. Then I will call the function on the click of a button. But the question is how can I throw back the updated items to the database?

Comment: I tried sql Update table Set column = datagridview column but it won't work.

Comment: I know the error is because I have to update many rows in one column. And something's missing with my query.. maybe a loop?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CellEndEdit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellendedit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this action
Your query can be like this:

```
query1 = "UPDATE urdatabaseTable SET urdatabaseColumn='" + 
                    dGV.CurrentCell.Value + "' WHERE id=" + dGV.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value;
```

be careful about [WHERE CLAUSE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp), you should use a constant value of your records like an ID or something else that specify your records.

Comment: Will this work without looping? Because I'm talking about updating 10-14 rows in one column..

Comment: yes its work fine with/without loops! actually whenever you finish your editing of your datagrid's cell & press enter or changing the index of current cells, this event will be start and your query will be executed

Comment: Ohh yeah I see. :) thanks for this. Maybe I'll just spare the button. :3

Answer (score 1):

The general syntax for updating from a [DataAdapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1z2bkx2(v=vs.110).aspx) is something like below;

```
myDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = myUpdateCommand;
myDataAdapter.Update(myDataTable);
```

Since calling above method will update you base datasource considering **all** your datatable changes you have to determine what event should call the above code to update your datasource from grid. If you want to update the datasource when your cell column updated you can use `CellEndEdit`. Otherwise you can use `form_close` event to update when all the changes are done and when closing the form.

Comment: Thanks. I will use form_close. :)